# Maximum Likelihood Estimator for a Random Sample from Bernoulli distribution

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

Given a random sample $X_1, X_2,..., X_n$ from Bernoulli distribution. The log-likelihood function is:

$\mathcal{L}(\theta) = \sum_1^n x_i^*\log{\theta} + (n - \sum_1^n x_i^*)\log{(1-\theta)}$

Score function:

$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\sum_1^n x_i^*}{\theta} - \frac{n - \sum_1^n x_i^*}{1 - \theta}   \; \forall \theta \in (0,1)$

By solving the score equation $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x} = 0 $ we get  $\theta = \bar{x}$ is a potential maximum likelihood estimate for $\theta$.

We need to verify that the second derivative is negative at $\theta = \bar{x}$.

$\frac{\partial^2 \mathcal{L}}{\partial^2 \theta} = -\frac{\sum_1^n x_i^*}{\theta^2} - \frac{n - \sum_1^n x_i^*}{(1 - \theta)^2}   \; \forall \theta \in (0,1)$

$\frac{\partial^2 \mathcal{L}}{\partial^2 \theta}\rvert_{\theta = \bar{x}} = -\frac{\sum_1^n x_i^*}{\bar{x}^2} - \frac{n - \sum_1^n x_i^*}{(1 - \bar{x})^2}$

At this step, some people will conclude immediately that the second derivative evaluated at maximum likelihood estimate is negative, so $\bar{X}$ is maximum likelihood estimator for $\theta$.

However, do I have to say that the second derivative is negative under the condition that $\bar{x} \neq 0$ and $ 1 - \bar{x} \neq 0$? Or is this constraint implied from the beginning? I just want everything to be completely precise.

I know that if $\bar{x} = n$ or $\bar{x} = 0$, the likelihood function will behave differently as it will have a reflection point, but the maximum likelihood estimate for these situations is still $\bar{x}$. Of course, we cannot use the method shown above to derive the maximum likelihood estimate.

Comment: I would say that it's arguably a problem... consider the likelihood of Be(1) where you have one realization which is 0, then your likelihood will be 0... by taking the log to transform it to log-likelihood, you have some problems because you would have log(0)

Comment: also, consider the case where $\bar{x} \in {0,1}$, then you have no entropy, since you have only events that you are sure to happen (aka BE(1), all the events are in one class, Be(0) all the events are in the other class).... therefore there is no variance in this "random variable", and the negative inverse of the second moment  is the variance of the estimator, and having it "1/infinite" means that your estimator is 100% accurate, which is fine for the condition presented

Answer (score 1):

I disagree that they would not exist. The second derivative is only a tool to find the global maximum of the likelihood function. We have the likelihood function

$$L(\theta)=\sum x_i \log \theta+(1-\sum x_i)\log(1-\theta),\theta\in[0,1]$$

If all the observations are successes, we get the likelihood

$$L(\theta)= n\log \theta$$

Since the function is increasing in $\theta$, we get $\hat\theta=1$. Similarly if all the observations are failures, we get the likelihood

$$L(\theta)=\log(1-\theta)$$

this is now decreasing in $\theta$ so we want the minimum possible $\theta$, which in the interval $[0,1]$ is $\hat\theta=0$. The moral of the story is that the second derivative can be used for the intermediary values but not the end points.